# Team Foundation Server deleted files are visible

Tags: file, tfs

In my company I use Team Foundation Server and the deleted folders are visible.

Why is that?

Comment: Toggle Show/Hide with extension. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-13343

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this before. It was quite annoying..but simple. In VS2013 at least, you should see this: [image: Show Hide Button]

Answer (score 3):

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server:

Show deleted items in Source Control Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Delete on folder is just a check-out on this folder with delete status. Simply check-in your change.